# Connect via AMQP to Azure IoT hub

Tags: azure, amqp, azure-iot-hub

I use Azure IoT HUB and I want connect to device and send/receive messages.

First of all I generate SaS token and connect to IoT HUB.

After this I create new device: create new certificate get thumbprint and set this thumbprint to new device.

At last I use certificate and connect to device via AMQP.
But get error after attaching:

> amqp:unauthorized-access

In attach packet target address is "devices/{device-id}/messages/events"

What's wrong? Why I get this error?

Comment: Can you show the code sample?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT code sample of what part?

Comment: A code sample is able to reproduce your issue. Have you generated, signed the X.509 certs?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT here my sample: https://github.com/bananaRanger/CertificateGenerator

Comment: @Anthony have you connect your device with AMQP if yes then please share a code of sample

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your passing the SaS token incorrectl. What language are you using? Are you using preexisting library or are you trying to implement AMQP by hand?

Have a look at [this post](https://paolopatierno.wordpress.com/2015/10/24/connecting-to-the-azure-iot-hub-using-an-the-amqp-stack/) for pretty good documentation, library sources can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite).

Comment: I think that my SaS token is correct, because I get list of devices by this token.
I use my own AMQP library and don't use any Azure library.
I implement my solution on Objective-C.

Comment: @Anthony The SAS tokens of getting the list of devices and connecting to a device are different. And the device uses X509 for authentication cannot be used with a SAS token.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I know that I must choose something one and i had chosen authentication with x.509. I use SaS token only for display list for devices to user.
But after I receive 'attach' response packet I receive 'detach' packet with error: 'amqp:unauthorized-access'

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT and I detected that 'attach' response packet has null properties (except for name and role)

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I try generate x.509 certificate [with iothub-explorer](https://github.com/Azure/iothub-explorer) but have the same error.